# Combine variations of the same domain in Google Analytics

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, google-analytics

Is there a way of forcing Google Analytics to combine variations of the same domain so it treats all subsequent visits from one user to any of these URLs as the same user? Here's an example:

```
http://www.example.com/mypage.php
https://www.example.com/mypage.php
http://example.com/mypage.php
https://example.com/mypage.php
```

What I hope to achieve is a setup where if a single user clicked each of these links, the results would appear in Analytics as:

```
http://www.example.com/mypage.php - Pageviews: 4   Users: 1
```

This question expands on [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1561514/does-google-analytics-combine-naked-domains-with-the-www-subdomain) from earlier

As I understand it, if I were to add a global `301 redirect` to my `.htaccess` file, the user would be automatically redirected to whatever domain I specify. Is this the best solution?

Answer (score 0):

The answer you linked to is outdated (if it was ever right). If you use Universal Analytics and set the cookie domain parameer to auto (which is the default) the cookie will be set for the domain and all subdomains:

> Automatic Cookie Domain Configuration simplifies cross domain tracking
>   implementations by automatically writing cookies to the highest level
>   domain possible when the auto parameter is used. When used on the
>   domain www.example.co.uk, it will try to write cookies in the
>   following order:
>
> co.uk
>
> example.co.uk
>
> www.example.co.uk

(see [documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/domains)). So you will have a cookie for example.co.uk on both domain and www subdomain which is valid for both.

Having said  that, you should still use the 301 for SEO reasons (to avoid duplicate content, plus Google announced last year that ssl is a ranking factor now so you might want to use your https pages only).